# getting result from database MySql/JAVA

Tags: java

I want to display the number (ID) in jTextField of the selected domaine in my jCombobox e.g if I selected 'informatique' in combobox it should display '1' as ID in the TextField 
I tried this but it dosen't work and this is my function

```
public void afficherF() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    DB con = new DB();
    con.connecte();
    String req = "SELECT ID FROM formation where domaine='" + jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
    ResultSet rs = con.stmt.executeQuery(req);
    rs.next();
    int num = rs.getInt(1);
    txt_f.setText(String.valueOf(num));
    System.out.println(num);

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it dosen't work"? Are you getting an exception? The wrong results?

Comment: yes I m getting this : Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

Comment: Consider using PreparesStatement

Comment: Use if (rs.next) {...} to test if the query has return any results

Comment: or .isBeforeFirst() method (similar isAfterLast()) on ResultSet to check if result set contains any row

Comment: now I don't get the exception but nothing is showing in the textField

Answer (score 1):

"java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set" - if you are getting this it means that your MySQL query returned 0 rows, on which you cant perform .getXX() method.

short example of PreparedStatement usage is here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html